# Why didn't PROXY have/use these combat modules?

Tags: star-wars, droids

Why didn't [PROXY](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/PROXY) have/use these combat modules: for example General Grievous or Mace Windu or even Yoda? Grievous would be a great challenge, Windu as well and Yoda? Would they be too hard, and that's why PROXY didn't have them?

---

I assume he has Grievous. I tweeted the author of Force Unleashed, no response.

Comment: What makes you think he didn't (for the obvious exception of Yoda, who is significantly smaller than PROXY).

Comment: The fact it is not mentioned in canon is hardly authoritative. The fact that we never see C-3P0 speaking Ithorian hardly means he couldn't. But I suspect he *could* do Grevious (he was mostly droid, anyway), and probably *could* do Windu, though he would lack the intensity fueled by Vaapad. Yoda would be the only one I would suspect he would lack, and that's if PROXY lacked the jumping/flipping capability.

Answer (score 2):

PROXY can probably do Mace Windu. Apparently, in order to execute a module perfectly requires PROXY to study and learn it. Not using Windu probably only means he is still preparing it.

Yoda...size matters, kid.

Grievous is an interesting case. PROXY does not appear to be built for combat with more than two hands. That is fine, since Grievous doesn't always go all-out. But in the game context, what is the point of fighting Grievous if he'll never go all six-limbed on you?